# How to connect 1" PVC pipe to 1" push fitting

Tags: pushfit

How do you push 1" PVC pipe into a 1" brass push fitting? It won't go in. Is a special tool needed?

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

I made a mistake. Push fittings only work with **CPVC**, pex or copper, not *PVC*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's likely the wrong fitting for the job.  Shark bite style fittings typically are for pec, Cpvc and copper.  Below is the list for branded products.

> ```
> Copper pipe hard drawn Type K, L and M and annealed Type M not to exceed 3/8 nominal, complying with ASTM B88
> PEX pipe complying with ASTM F 876 or CSA B137.5
> CPVC pipe complying with ASTM D 2846 or CSA B137.6
> PE-RT pipe complying with ASTM F 276
> ```